# Why is my texture actilng like a color?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I'm pretty new to blender, and i wanted to try to render something pretty simple, so i made a house. But the problem is, that when i try to apply my seamless texture to roof, it is showing/acting like color. I really don't know why, because the texture is ok.
I have tried to figure it out using nodes, but i didn't came up with a solution...

[image: This is how to roof looks like rendered]

Comment: Did you UV unwrap your geometry? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/11060/texture-doesnt-render-with-cycles?rq=1 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6827/texture-is-missing-in-cycles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to connect your UV Data to the Vector Input of your Texture Node:
[image: Shifft+A > Input > UV Map or <br> Shifft+A > Input > Texture Coordinate : Genereated, <br> Connect the output to the Vector Input]

Use <kbd>Shifft</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > Input > UV Map to specify your UV Map or use `Generated` of the Texture Coordinate Node if you don't want to unwrap your Object.

Comment: @gandalf3 No, the uv map node was added as part of 2.71.

Comment: Oh oops, sorry..