# Why is my textured material showing up as a solid color?

Tags: texturing

[image]

I'm trying to use a simple oak texture on this cube but it just shows up as a solid color.

I tried every option in the image texture (linear, cubic, flat, etc.) none of them worked in fact  I saw no difference between them.

Comment: Much more viable option is to unwrap the mesh first and use *UV* output socket from the *Texture Coordinates* node (though using any other coordinates may work depending on your needs). See also -http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14239/why-is-my-texture-actilng-like-a-color, http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6827/texture-is-missing-in-cycles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have Cycles render engine enabled?
If so, try adding a texture coordinate into the vector input to tell blender how to wrap the texture to a given object.
[image]