# Texture rendering as solid color, in spite of mapping?

Tags: texturing, materials, graph-editor

Newbie to Blender here, running Blender 2.9. I'm following a tutorial to create a city, but getting stuck on applying a textured material. It's only coming out as a solid color. So far I've tried...

- Switching between Cycles and Eevee
- Adding mapping & texture coordinate nodes (as suggested here: [Why is my textured material showing up as a solid color?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49001/why-is-my-textured-material-showing-up-as-a-solid-color))
- Changing the texture coordinate nodes between "generated" and "UV"
- Changing the scale on the mapping

Here is the shader graph I have on mythology  material:

[image: Shader graph]

And here is how the material is showing up on the model:

[image: Model]

Comment: Try changing from *Point* to *Texture* in the *Mapping* node

Comment: Are your meshes unwrapped? Are your meshes being created by modifiers, like Geometry Nodes?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Unfortunately it had no effect

Comment: @Nathan Textures are indeed unwrapped (via "smart UV unwrap") and meshes are not generated (I don't think) they were imported from a map file

Comment: Then I suppose I'd need to see a file to tell you what's going on (other than the fact that the mapping node you're showing isn't doing anything.)  With a packed image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and it was stupid. Not only did the texture need to be scaled down, it was coming in rotated at 90 degrees for some reason. Which, due to its imagery, made it just look like a solid color.

Lesson for next time: don't just play around with location and scale settings on mapping, do rotation as well!